# How to generate Transliteration of Bengali word?

Tags: xetex, transliteration

I need to generate Transliteration of Bangla/Bengali words into latin. For example a newcommand,

```
\generateTransliteration{আমার সোনার বাংলা}
```

will provide result = "**Āmāra sōnāra bānlā**"

As far I know, there is no package or command to do this for Bangla/Bengali language. If there is really no command available, how can I generate it by my own with newcommand. I think, I have to map between the ISO 15919 to latin characters. However, I don't know how to do this. [I have read several stackexchange questions/answers on Devanagari and Sanskrit, but they are not exactly this problem]. Compiler: Xetex, Language: Bangla/Bengali . Thank you

Comment: it would be easier in luatex or an external program than in xetex, although if you linked to a specification of the transliteration mapping then it is probably doable in xetex as well.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But I am using xetex. Thus, I need the solution in xetex. Can you help me with a simple/sample transliteration mapping in xetex? Thank you.

Comment: I guess you need mapping from column 5 to column 1 of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15919 ?

Comment: Are you sure you need xetex rather than luatex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes exactly. column 5 to column 1. Could you please help me implement this in xetex? Thank you.

Comment: possibly but later, out  of time now

Comment: where did the capital A come from in your version? Was that a post-translitaeration capitalise first letter of the string, or would you need some letters within the string to be capitalised?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Taking the data from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15919  make a mapping table `b-map.tex`

like so `b-map.tex`

```
\zztable{
\zzrow{.}{।}
\zzrow{ā}{া}
\zzrow{i}{ি}
\zzrow{ī}{ী}
\zzrow{u}{ু}
\zzrow{ū}{ূ}
\zzrow{ō}{ো}
\zzrow{ē}{ে}
\zzrow{ai}{ৈ}
\zzrow{au}{ৌ}
\zzrow{a}{অ}
\zzrow{ā}{আ}
\zzrow{i}{ই}
\zzrow{ī}{ঈ}
\zzrow{u}{উ}
\zzrow{ū}{ঊ}
\zzrow{r̥}{ঋ}
\zzrow{r̥̄}{ৠ}
\zzrow{l̥}{ঌ}
\zzrow{l̥̄}{ৡ}
\zzrow{ē}{এ}
\zzrow{ai}{ঐ}
\zzrow{ō}{ও}
\zzrow{au}{ঔ}
\zzrow{n}{ং}
\zzrow{m̐}{ঁ}
\zzrow{ḥ}{ঃ}
\zzrow{k}{ক}
\zzrow{kh}{খ}
\zzrow{g}{গ}
\zzrow{gh}{ঘ}
\zzrow{ṅ}{ঙ}
\zzrow{c}{চ}
\zzrow{ch}{ছ}
\zzrow{j}{জ}
\zzrow{jh}{ঝ}
\zzrow{ñ}{ঞ}
\zzrow{ṭ}{ট}
\zzrow{ṭh}{ঠ}
\zzrow{ḍ}{ড}
\zzrow{ḍh}{ঢ}
\zzrow{ṛ}{ড়}
\zzrow{ṛh}{ঢ়}
\zzrow{ṇ}{ণ}
\zzrow{t}{ত}
\zzrow{th}{থ}
\zzrow{d}{দ}
\zzrow{dh}{ধ}
\zzrow{n}{ন}
\zzrow{p}{প}
\zzrow{ph}{ফ}
\zzrow{b}{ব}
\zzrow{bh}{ভ}
\zzrow{m}{ম}
\zzrow{y}{য} 
\zzrow{ẏ}{য়}\zzrow{ẏ}{য়}
\zzrow{r}{র}
\zzrow{l}{ল}
\zzrow{ś}{শ}
\zzrow{ṣ}{ষ}
\zzrow{s}{স}
\zzrow{h}{হ}
\zzrow{’}{ঽ}
\zzrow{q}{ক়}
\zzrow{k͟h}{খ়}
\zzrow{ġ}{গ়}
\zzrow{z}{জ়}
\zzrow{f}{ফ়}
}
```

Then you can get xetex to read it as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\tracinglostchars2
\makeatletter
\def\zztable#1{#1}
\def\zzrow#1#2{\expandafter\gdef\csname B-#2\endcsname{#1}}
\def\generateTransliteration#1{\xgenerateTransliteration#1@}
\def\xgenerateTransliteration{\futurelet\tmp\xxgenerateTransliteration}
\def\xxgenerateTransliteration{%
\ifx\tmp\@sptoken\space\fi
\xxxgenerateTransliteration
}
\def\xxxgenerateTransliteration#1{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname B-#1\endcsname\relax?%
\expandafter\show\csname B-#1\endcsname
\fi
\csname B-#1\endcsname
\xgenerateTransliteration}
\expandafter\def\csname B-@\endcsname#1{}
\makeatother

\input{b-map}
\begin{document}


Here: \generateTransliteration{আমার সোনার বাংলা}

\end{document}
```

there are some letters missing from the table which produce a `\show` error in the log and typeset as ? hopefully you can extend the table, as I can't read the script I got lost checking if the data was missing in wikipedia or if I lost it while editing the table to tex syntax.

You might also want to add punctuation characters if they transliterate to themselves.

Note latin modern doesn't have U+1E41 (m with dot accent) so I used Times New Roman here, an alternative would be to set that character up to use a cinstructed accent)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. I have added missing characters. However, it has space problem. Words are not separated. I tried `\zzrow{ }{ }` but not working.

Comment: it had code to re-insert spaces but I may have messed up (I was out of time this morning), can you edit my answer to add your extended mapping file then I'll check @NahidHossain

Comment: I don't know, but space is working all of a sudden. Thank you. Everything is working perfectly fine. Except a character "য়" which is "ẏ", it is already in the map `\zzrow{ẏ}{য়}` .  However, it is still shows "?" in the place of that specific character only. For example, in the word "বলয়", instead of 'blẏ', it shows "bl?". However as you can see the character mapping for "য়" exists. Please help.

Comment: @NahidHossain look at https://mathml-refresh.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?%7B%E0%A7%9F%7D%0A%5Czzrow%7B%E1%BA%8F%7D%7B%E0%A6%AF%E0%A6%BC%7D   the maping file has the combining pair YA NUKTA but your example has YYA I aded a second mapping for Y-dot

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about Bengali and so I don't know if these combination glyphs can be universally decoded piecemeal as I have done here, or whether they need to be decoded as a combined unit.

By this, I mean that some of the glyphs are composite.  For example, `বাং`, upon digestion, expands to three characters `ব`, `া`, and `ং`.  In this decomposition, according to my instructions, it transliterates to `b`, `ā`, and `n`.  However, I do not know if `ং` always transliterates to `n`, or only when following these prior glyphs.  I am assuming a once-always transliteration, however, I am open to hearing how that might not be the case.

I also do not know about letter case in Bengali, and so my mapping followed the OP's lead, though it appears there may not actually be a letter case in the language.

I have only shown the `\tcmapto`s corresponding to the characters in the OP's expression.  However, I used https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/bengali/ to help me with the maps (and a hex to decimal converter), to know the character codes corresponding to each character, etc.  Other glyphs can be added from there to the `\tcmapto`.  I allow the mappings in terms of the glyph itself, or the unicode slot with `\tcmapnumto` (as shown in MWE comments).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\def\tcmapto#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapto\number`#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\tcmapnumto#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapto#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\tcremap#1{\ifcsname tcmapto\number`#1\endcsname
                 \csname tcmapto\number`#1\endcsname\else#1\fi}

\tcmapto{ং}{n}% OR \tcmapnumto{2434}{n}
\tcmapto{আ}{Ā}% OR \tcmapnumto{2438}{Ā}
\tcmapto{ন}{n}% OR \tcmapnumto{2472}{n}
\tcmapto{ব}{b}% OR \tcmapnumto{2476}{b}
\tcmapto{ম}{m}% OR \tcmapnumto{2478}{m}
\tcmapto{র}{ra}% OR \tcmapnumto{2480}{ra}
\tcmapto{ল}{l}% OR \tcmapnumto{2482}{l}
\tcmapto{স}{s}% OR \tcmapnumto{2488}{s}
\tcmapto{া}{ā}% OR \tcmapnumto{2494}{ā}
\tcmapto{ো}{ō}% OR \tcmapnumto{2507}{ō}

\begin{document}
\Characterdirective{\addcytoks[x]{\tcremap{#1}}}
\tokencyclexpress
আমার সোনার বাংলা

আ-মা-র  সো-না-র  বাং-লা
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use regular expressions and the replace function, with `expl3` syntax. It can run under xelatex or lualatex.

[image: Example]

The mapping can be easily updated.

Longest substrings must be replaced first, as always with find/replace.

First iteration:

[image: Solar System]

Article from Wikipedia: solar system.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newfontface\translitfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\bengalifont{Noto Sans Bengali}[Script=Bengali,Renderer=HarfBuzz,Colour=blue]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_mytrans_tl

% transliteration
\NewDocumentCommand{\indictrans}{ m }
{
\tl_set:Nn \l_mytrans_tl { #1 }
\doindictrans
    { \translitfont
                    \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl
        }
}

% text (transliteration)
\NewDocumentCommand{\indictransg}{ m }
{
    #1 ~ (
\tl_set:Nn \l_mytrans_tl { #1 }
\doindictrans
    { \translitfont
                    \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl
        } )
}

% multi-line environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{isoindictranse}{ +b }
{
\tl_set:Nn \l_mytrans_tl { #1 }
\doindictrans
%\bengalifont
    { \translitfont
                    \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl
        }
}
{ }

% the mapping
\newcommand\doindictrans{
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ড় } { r^^^^0323a } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঢ় } { r^^^^0323ha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { য় } { y^^^^0307a } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ক় } { qa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { খ় } { k͟ha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { গ় } { g^^^^0307a } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { জ় } { za } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ফ় } { fa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { অ } { a } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { আ } { ā } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ই } { i } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঈ } { ī } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { উ } { u } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঊ } { ū } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঋ } { r̥ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৠ } { r̥̄ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঌ } { l̥ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৡ } { l̥̄ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { এ } { ē } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঐ } { ai } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ও } { ō } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঔ } { au } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ং } { ṁ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঁ } { m̐ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঃ } { ḥ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ক } { ka } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { খ } { kha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { গ } { ga } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঘ } { gha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঙ } { ṅa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { চ } { ca } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ছ } { cha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { জ } { ja } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঝ } { jha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঞ } { ña } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ট } { ṭa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঠ } { ṭha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ড } { ḍa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঢ } { ḍha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ণ } { ṇa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ত } { ta } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { থ } { tha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { দ } { da } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ধ } { dha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ন } { na } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { প } { pa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ফ } { pha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ব } { ba } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ভ } { bha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ম } { ma } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { য } { ya } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { র } { ra } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৰ } { ra } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ল } { la } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৱ } { va } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { শ } { śa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ষ } { ṣa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { স } { sa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { হ } { ha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঽ } { ’ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { । } { . } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { া } { -ā } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ি } { -i } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ী } { -ī } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ু } { -u } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ূ } { -ū } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৃ } { -r } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৄ } { -rr } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ে } { -e } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৈ } { -ai } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ো } { -o } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৌ } { -au } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ্ } {  virama } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৎ } { t } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৗ } { - } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ০ } { 0 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ১ } { 1 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ২ } { 2 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৩ } { 3 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৪ } { 4 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৫ } { 5 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৬ } { 6 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৭ } { 7 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৮ } { 8 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৯ } { 9 } 


% tidy-up: inherent a, etc
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-(ai) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-(au) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-([āiueoīū]{1}) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-(rr) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-(r) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { avirama } { } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ṁ } { ng } 
\regex_replace_all:nnN { \-([āiueoīū]{1}) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
%...
}
 


\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\bengalifont
\begin{multicols}{5}
\noindent অ (\indictrans{অ})\par
\noindent আ (\indictrans{আ})\par
\noindent ই (\indictrans{ই})\par
\noindent ঈ (\indictrans{ঈ})\par
\noindent উ (\indictrans{উ})\par
\noindent ঊ (\indictrans{ঊ})\par
\noindent ঋ (\indictrans{ঋ})\par
\noindent ৠ (\indictrans{ৠ})\par
\noindent ঌ (\indictrans{ঌ})\par
\noindent ৡ (\indictrans{ৡ})\par
\noindent এ (\indictrans{এ})\par
\noindent ঐ (\indictrans{ঐ})\par
\noindent ও (\indictrans{ও})\par
\noindent ঔ (\indictrans{ঔ})\par
\noindent ং (\indictrans{ং})\par
\noindent ঁ (\indictrans{ঁ})\par
\noindent ঃ (\indictrans{ঃ})\par
\noindent ক (\indictrans{ক})\par
\noindent খ (\indictrans{খ})\par
\noindent গ (\indictrans{গ})\par
\noindent ঘ (\indictrans{ঘ})\par
\noindent ঙ (\indictrans{ঙ})\par
\noindent চ (\indictrans{চ})\par
\noindent ছ (\indictrans{ছ})\par
\noindent জ (\indictrans{জ})\par
\noindent ঝ (\indictrans{ঝ})\par
\noindent ঞ (\indictrans{ঞ})\par
\noindent ট (\indictrans{ট})\par
\noindent ঠ (\indictrans{ঠ})\par
\noindent ড (\indictrans{ড})\par
\noindent ঢ (\indictrans{ঢ})\par
\noindent ড় (\indictrans{ড়})\par
\noindent ঢ় (\indictrans{ঢ়})\par
\noindent ণ (\indictrans{ণ})\par
\noindent ত (\indictrans{ত})\par
\noindent থ (\indictrans{থ})\par
\noindent দ (\indictrans{দ})\par
\noindent ধ (\indictrans{ধ})\par
\noindent ন (\indictrans{ন})\par
\noindent প (\indictrans{প})\par
\noindent ফ (\indictrans{ফ})\par
\noindent ব (\indictrans{ব})\par
\noindent ভ (\indictrans{ভ})\par
\noindent ম (\indictrans{ম})\par
\noindent য (\indictrans{য})\par
\noindent য় (\indictrans{য়})\par
\noindent র (\indictrans{র})\par
\noindent ৰ (\indictrans{ৰ})\par
\noindent ল (\indictrans{ল})\par
\noindent ৱ (\indictrans{ৱ})\par
\noindent শ (\indictrans{শ})\par
\noindent ষ (\indictrans{ষ})\par
\noindent স (\indictrans{স})\par
\noindent হ (\indictrans{হ})\par
\noindent ঽ (\indictrans{ঽ})\par
\noindent ক় (\indictrans{ক়})\par
\noindent খ় (\indictrans{খ়})\par
\noindent গ় (\indictrans{গ়})\par
\noindent জ় (\indictrans{জ়})\par
\noindent ফ় (\indictrans{ফ়})\par
\noindent । (\indictrans{।})\par
\noindent া (\indictrans{া})\par
\noindent ি (\indictrans{ি})\par
\noindent ী (\indictrans{ী})\par
\noindent ু (\indictrans{ু})\par
\noindent ূ (\indictrans{ূ})\par
\noindent ৃ (\indictrans{ৃ})\par
\noindent ৄ (\indictrans{ৄ})\par
\noindent ে (\indictrans{ে})\par
\noindent ৈ (\indictrans{ৈ})\par
\noindent ো (\indictrans{ো})\par
\noindent ৌ (\indictrans{ৌ})\par
\noindent ্ (\indictrans{্})\par
\noindent ৎ (\indictrans{ৎ})\par
\noindent ৗ (\indictrans{ৗ})\par
\noindent ০ (\indictrans{০})\par
\noindent ১ (\indictrans{১})\par
\noindent ২ (\indictrans{২})\par
\noindent ৩ (\indictrans{৩})\par
\noindent ৪ (\indictrans{৪})\par
\noindent ৫ (\indictrans{৫})\par
\noindent ৬ (\indictrans{৬})\par
\noindent ৭ (\indictrans{৭})\par
\noindent ৮ (\indictrans{৮})\par
\noindent ৯ (\indictrans{৯})\par
\end{multicols}

\indictransg{আমার সোনার বাংলা}

\indictransg{সৌরজগৎ}

\begin{isoindictranse}


সৌরজগৎ হল সূর্য ও প্রত্যক্ষ বা পরোক্ষভাবে[ক] সূর্য-প্রদক্ষিণকারী তথা পরস্পরের প্রতি অভিকর্ষজ টানে আবদ্ধ মহাজাগতিক বস্তুগুলিকে নিয়ে গড়ে একটি ব্যবস্থা। আকাশগঙ্গা ছায়াপথের কেন্দ্রস্থল থেকে ২৬,০০০ আলোকবর্ষ দূরে কালপুরুষ বাহুতে এই গ্রহ ব্যবস্থাটি অবস্থিত। সৌরজগতে প্রত্যক্ষভাবে সূর্য-প্রদক্ষিণকারী বস্তুগুলির মধ্যে আটটি গ্রহই বৃহত্তম।[খ] অন্য ক্ষুদ্রতর বস্তুগুলির মধ্যে রয়েছে বামন গ্রহ ও সৌরজগতের ক্ষুদ্র বস্তুসমূহ। পরোক্ষভাবে সূর্য-প্রদক্ষিণকারী বস্তুগুলির মধ্যে দু’টি প্রাকৃতিক উপগ্রহ ক্ষুদ্রতম গ্রহ বুধের থেকেও আকারে বড়ো।[গ] 
\end{isoindictranse}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

use \banglatranslit command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bangla}

\begin{document}
    \banglatranslit{আমার সোনার বাংলা}
\end{document}
```