# How to generate phonetic transliteration from English to Bengali?

Tags: transliteration, phonetic

I want to generate phonetic text from English to Bengali words in unicode.
For example, if I write,

```
\bn{ami vat khai}
```

I want the output be like `"আমি ভাত খাই"`

So my question is: **How can I generate phonetic Bengali text from English?**

Comment: The inverse problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597535/how-to-generate-transliteration-of-bengali-word

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use expl3 `replace` function, or `regex` function.

A one-to-one mapping is required, from English to Bengali; you can decide what string values to use on the English side to become the Bengali values.

Here I illustrate using ASCII characters on plain keyboard.

[image: one to one]

Because English has so few characters, using single letters is not enough. Therefore combinations of English letters are needed in some cases to make the one-to-one, example: `a=` is used for `অ`, `aa=` for `আ` because `aa` is used for `া`, and so on.

Use `/` to split a string that would otherwise be parsed incorrectly, example: to stop the sequence `aai=` being misread as `a` + `ai=`(ঐ), use `/`: `aa/i=` which is then read as `aa` (া) + `i=` (ই) and `/` is removed from the output. To get a `/` in the output, type `//`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newfontface\translitfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\bengalifont{Noto Sans Bengali}[Script=Bengali,Renderer=HarfBuzz,Colour=blue]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_mytrans_tl



% transliteration: Latin-to-Bangla
\NewDocumentCommand{\bn}{ m }
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_mytrans_tl { #1 }

    \dobntrans
        
    { \bengalifont
                    \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl
        }
}

\newcommand\dobntrans{
%
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { // } { xxx } 
%
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { mmcb } { ঁ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { hlnt } { ্ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { aa= } { আ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ii= } { ঈ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { uu= } { ঊ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { rr= } { ৠ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ll= } { ৡ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ee= } { এ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ai= } { ঐ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { oo= } { ও } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { au= } { ঔ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { tth } { ঠ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ddh } { ঢ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { rrr } { ড় } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { rrh } { ণ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { -rr } { ৄ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { -aa } { া } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { a= } { অ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { i= } { ই } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { u= } { উ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { r= } { ঋ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { l= } { ঌ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { mm } { ং } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { hh } { ঃ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { kh } { খ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { gh } { ঘ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { nn } { ঙ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ch } { ছ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { jh } { ঝ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ny } { ঞ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { tt } { ট } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { dd } { ড } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { rr } { ঢ় } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { th } { থ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { dh } { ধ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ph } { ফ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { bh } { ভ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { yy } { য় } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { rm } { ৰ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { sh } { শ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ss } { ষ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { qh } { খ় } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { gg } { গ় } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { aa } { া } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ii } { ী } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { uu } { ূ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { -r } { ৃ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ai } { ৈ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { au } { ৌ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { t- } { ৎ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { k } { ক } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { g } { গ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { c } { চ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { j } { জ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { t } { ত } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { d } { দ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { n } { ন } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { p } { প } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { b } { ব } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { m } { ম } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { y } { য } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { r } { র } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { l } { ল } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { v } { ৱ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { s } { স } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { h } { হ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ’ } { ঽ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { q } { ক় } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { z } { জ় } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { f } { ফ় } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { . } { । } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { i } { ি } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { u } { ু } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { e } { ে } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { o } { ো } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { - } { ৗ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 0 } { ০ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 1 } { ১ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 2 } { ২ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 3 } { ৩ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 4 } { ৪ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 5 } { ৫ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 6 } { ৬ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 7 } { ৭ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 8 } { ৮ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 9 } { ৯ } 
% tidy-up: inherent a, etc
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { a } {  } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { / } {  } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { xxx } {  } 

}



%-----------------------------------
% transliteration: Bangla-to-Latin
\NewDocumentCommand{\indictrans}{ m }
{
\tl_set:Nn \l_mytrans_tl { #1 }
\doindictrans
    { \translitfont
                    \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl
        }
}

% text (transliteration)
\NewDocumentCommand{\indictransg}{ m }
{
    #1 ~ (
\tl_set:Nn \l_mytrans_tl { #1 }
\doindictrans
    { \translitfont
                    \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl
        } )
}

% multi-line environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{isoindictranse}{ +b }
{
\tl_set:Nn \l_mytrans_tl { #1 }
\doindictrans
%\bengalifont
    { \translitfont
                    \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl
        }
}
{ }

% the mapping
\newcommand\doindictrans{
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ড় } { r^^^^0323a } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঢ় } { r^^^^0323ha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { য় } { y^^^^0307a } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ক় } { qa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { খ় } { k͟ha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { গ় } { g^^^^0307a } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { জ় } { za } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ফ় } { fa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { অ } { a } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { আ } { ā } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ই } { i } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঈ } { ī } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { উ } { u } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঊ } { ū } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঋ } { r̥ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৠ } { r̥̄ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঌ } { l̥ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৡ } { l̥̄ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { এ } { ē } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঐ } { ai } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ও } { ō } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঔ } { au } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ং } { ṁ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঁ } { m̐ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঃ } { ḥ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ক } { ka } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { খ } { kha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { গ } { ga } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঘ } { gha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঙ } { ṅa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { চ } { ca } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ছ } { cha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { জ } { ja } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঝ } { jha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঞ } { ña } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ট } { ṭa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঠ } { ṭha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ড } { ḍa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঢ } { ḍha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ণ } { ṇa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ত } { ta } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { থ } { tha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { দ } { da } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ধ } { dha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ন } { na } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { প } { pa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ফ } { pha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ব } { ba } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ভ } { bha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ম } { ma } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { য } { ya } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { র } { ra } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৰ } { ra } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ল } { la } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৱ } { va } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { শ } { śa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ষ } { ṣa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { স } { sa } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { হ } { ha } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ঽ } { ’ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { । } { . } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { া } { -ā } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ি } { -i } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ী } { -ī } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ু } { -u } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ূ } { -ū } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৃ } { -r } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৄ } { -rr } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ে } { -e } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৈ } { -ai } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ো } { -o } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৌ } { -au } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ্ } {  virama } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৎ } { t } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৗ } { - } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ০ } { 0 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ১ } { 1 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ২ } { 2 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৩ } { 3 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৪ } { 4 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৫ } { 5 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৬ } { 6 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৭ } { 7 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৮ } { 8 } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ৯ } { 9 } 


% tidy-up: inherent a, etc
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-(ai) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-(au) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-([āiueoīū]{1}) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-(rr) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { a\-(r) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { avirama } { } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ṁ } { ng } 
\regex_replace_all:nnN { \-([āiueoīū]{1}) } { \1 } \l_mytrans_tl
%...
}
 


\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\section{Latin to Bangla}

\textbackslash bn\{a=mi bhaat kh-aa/i=\}
$\mapsto$
\bn{a=mi bhaat kh-aa/i=}

\begin{multicols}{5}
\noindent a= (\bn{a=})\par
\noindent aa= (\bn{aa=})\par


\noindent i= (\bn{i=})\par
\noindent ii= (\bn{ii=})\par
\noindent u= (\bn{u=})\par
\noindent uu= (\bn{uu=})\par

\noindent r= (\bn{r=})\par
\noindent rr= (\bn{rr=})\par
\noindent l= (\bn{l=})\par
\noindent ll= (\bn{ll=})\par

\noindent ee= (\bn{ee=})\par

\noindent ai= (\bn{ai=})\par

\noindent oo= (\bn{oo=})\par

\noindent au= (\bn{au=})\par
\noindent mm (\bn{mm})\par

\noindent mmcb (\bn{mmcb})\par

\noindent hh (\bn{hh})\par



\noindent k (\bn{k})\par
\noindent kh (\bn{kh})\par
\noindent g (\bn{g})\par
\noindent gh (\bn{gh})\par
\noindent nn (\bn{nn})\par

\noindent c (\bn{c})\par

\noindent ch (\bn{ch})\par
\noindent j (\bn{j})\par
\noindent jh (\bn{jh})\par
\noindent ny (\bn{ny})\par

\noindent tt (\bn{tt})\par
\noindent tth (\bn{tth})\par
\noindent dd (\bn{dd})\par
\noindent ddh (\bn{ddh})\par
\noindent rrr (\bn{rrr})\par
\noindent rr (\bn{rr})\par
\noindent rrh (\bn{rrh})\par

\noindent t (\bn{t})\par
\noindent th (\bn{th})\par
\noindent d (\bn{d})\par
\noindent dh (\bn{dh})\par
\noindent n (\bn{n})\par

\noindent p (\bn{p})\par
\noindent ph (\bn{ph})\par
\noindent b (\bn{b})\par
\noindent bh (\bn{bh})\par
\noindent m (\bn{m})\par





\noindent y (\bn{y})\par
\noindent yy (\bn{yy})\par
\noindent r (\bn{r})\par
\noindent rm (\bn{rm})\par

\noindent l (\bn{l})\par

\noindent v (\bn{v})\par
\noindent sh (\bn{sh})\par
\noindent ss (\bn{ss})\par
\noindent s (\bn{s})\par
\noindent h (\bn{h})\par
\noindent ’ (\bn{’})\par
\noindent q (\bn{q})\par
\noindent qh (\bn{qh})\par
\noindent gg (\bn{gg})\par
\noindent z (\bn{z})\par
\noindent f (\bn{f})\par










\noindent . (\bn{.})\par
\noindent aa (\bn{aa})\par
\noindent i (\bn{i})\par
\noindent ii (\bn{ii})\par
\noindent u (\bn{u})\par
\noindent uu (\bn{uu})\par
\noindent -r (\bn{-r})\par
\noindent -rr (\bn{-rr})\par
\noindent e (\bn{e})\par
\noindent ai (\bn{ai})\par
\noindent o (\bn{o})\par
\noindent au (\bn{au})\par
\noindent hlnt (\bn{hlnt})\par
\noindent t- (\bn{t-})\par
\noindent - (\bn{-})\par
\noindent 0 (\bn{0})\par
\noindent 1 (\bn{1})\par
\noindent 2 (\bn{2})\par
\noindent 3 (\bn{3})\par
\noindent 4 (\bn{4})\par
\noindent 5 (\bn{5})\par
\noindent 6 (\bn{6})\par
\noindent 7 (\bn{7})\par
\noindent 8 (\bn{8})\par
\noindent 9 (\bn{9})\par
\noindent -aa (\bn{-aa})\par
\end{multicols}



\section{Bangla to Latin}
\bengalifont
\begin{multicols}{5}
\noindent অ (\indictrans{অ})\par
\noindent আ (\indictrans{আ})\par
\noindent ই (\indictrans{ই})\par
\noindent ঈ (\indictrans{ঈ})\par
\noindent উ (\indictrans{উ})\par
\noindent ঊ (\indictrans{ঊ})\par
\noindent ঋ (\indictrans{ঋ})\par
\noindent ৠ (\indictrans{ৠ})\par
\noindent ঌ (\indictrans{ঌ})\par
\noindent ৡ (\indictrans{ৡ})\par
\noindent এ (\indictrans{এ})\par
\noindent ঐ (\indictrans{ঐ})\par
\noindent ও (\indictrans{ও})\par
\noindent ঔ (\indictrans{ঔ})\par
\noindent ং (\indictrans{ং})\par
\noindent ঁ (\indictrans{ঁ})\par
\noindent ঃ (\indictrans{ঃ})\par
\noindent ক (\indictrans{ক})\par
\noindent খ (\indictrans{খ})\par
\noindent গ (\indictrans{গ})\par
\noindent ঘ (\indictrans{ঘ})\par
\noindent ঙ (\indictrans{ঙ})\par
\noindent চ (\indictrans{চ})\par
\noindent ছ (\indictrans{ছ})\par
\noindent জ (\indictrans{জ})\par
\noindent ঝ (\indictrans{ঝ})\par
\noindent ঞ (\indictrans{ঞ})\par
\noindent ট (\indictrans{ট})\par
\noindent ঠ (\indictrans{ঠ})\par
\noindent ড (\indictrans{ড})\par
\noindent ঢ (\indictrans{ঢ})\par
\noindent ড় (\indictrans{ড়})\par
\noindent ঢ় (\indictrans{ঢ়})\par
\noindent ণ (\indictrans{ণ})\par
\noindent ত (\indictrans{ত})\par
\noindent থ (\indictrans{থ})\par
\noindent দ (\indictrans{দ})\par
\noindent ধ (\indictrans{ধ})\par
\noindent ন (\indictrans{ন})\par
\noindent প (\indictrans{প})\par
\noindent ফ (\indictrans{ফ})\par
\noindent ব (\indictrans{ব})\par
\noindent ভ (\indictrans{ভ})\par
\noindent ম (\indictrans{ম})\par
\noindent য (\indictrans{য})\par
\noindent য় (\indictrans{য়})\par
\noindent র (\indictrans{র})\par
\noindent ৰ (\indictrans{ৰ})\par
\noindent ল (\indictrans{ল})\par
\noindent ৱ (\indictrans{ৱ})\par
\noindent শ (\indictrans{শ})\par
\noindent ষ (\indictrans{ষ})\par
\noindent স (\indictrans{স})\par
\noindent হ (\indictrans{হ})\par
\noindent ঽ (\indictrans{ঽ})\par
\noindent ক় (\indictrans{ক়})\par
\noindent খ় (\indictrans{খ়})\par
\noindent গ় (\indictrans{গ়})\par
\noindent জ় (\indictrans{জ়})\par
\noindent ফ় (\indictrans{ফ়})\par
\noindent । (\indictrans{।})\par
\noindent া (\indictrans{া})\par
\noindent ি (\indictrans{ি})\par
\noindent ী (\indictrans{ী})\par
\noindent ু (\indictrans{ু})\par
\noindent ূ (\indictrans{ূ})\par
\noindent ৃ (\indictrans{ৃ})\par
\noindent ৄ (\indictrans{ৄ})\par
\noindent ে (\indictrans{ে})\par
\noindent ৈ (\indictrans{ৈ})\par
\noindent ো (\indictrans{ো})\par
\noindent ৌ (\indictrans{ৌ})\par
\noindent ্ (\indictrans{্})\par
\noindent ৎ (\indictrans{ৎ})\par
\noindent ৗ (\indictrans{ৗ})\par
\noindent ০ (\indictrans{০})\par
\noindent ১ (\indictrans{১})\par
\noindent ২ (\indictrans{২})\par
\noindent ৩ (\indictrans{৩})\par
\noindent ৪ (\indictrans{৪})\par
\noindent ৫ (\indictrans{৫})\par
\noindent ৬ (\indictrans{৬})\par
\noindent ৭ (\indictrans{৭})\par
\noindent ৮ (\indictrans{৮})\par
\noindent ৯ (\indictrans{৯})\par
\end{multicols}

\indictransg{আমার সোনার বাংলা}

\indictransg{সৌরজগৎ}

\begin{isoindictranse}


সৌরজগৎ হল সূর্য ও প্রত্যক্ষ বা পরোক্ষভাবে[ক] সূর্য-প্রদক্ষিণকারী তথা পরস্পরের প্রতি অভিকর্ষজ টানে আবদ্ধ মহাজাগতিক বস্তুগুলিকে নিয়ে গড়ে একটি ব্যবস্থা। আকাশগঙ্গা ছায়াপথের কেন্দ্রস্থল থেকে ২৬,০০০ আলোকবর্ষ দূরে কালপুরুষ বাহুতে এই গ্রহ ব্যবস্থাটি অবস্থিত। সৌরজগতে প্রত্যক্ষভাবে সূর্য-প্রদক্ষিণকারী বস্তুগুলির মধ্যে আটটি গ্রহই বৃহত্তম।[খ] অন্য ক্ষুদ্রতর বস্তুগুলির মধ্যে রয়েছে বামন গ্রহ ও সৌরজগতের ক্ষুদ্র বস্তুসমূহ। পরোক্ষভাবে সূর্য-প্রদক্ষিণকারী বস্তুগুলির মধ্যে দু’টি প্রাকৃতিক উপগ্রহ ক্ষুদ্রতম গ্রহ বুধের থেকেও আকারে বড়ো।[গ] 
\end{isoindictranse}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Partly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597535/how-to-generate-transliteration-of-bengali-word  Transliteration in the reverse direction, Bengali to Latin letters.

Comment: [Cicada](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182648/cicada) I am having problem with space. I just edited your code and compiled. But there are a lot of spaces in my output. my code: `\section{\bn{banglay likhi}}
\bn{a=mader desh bangladesh. a=mra banglay ktha bli. bangladesh e=kTi chOToT desh. e=Ti dkoShiN e=Siya mHadeshe o=bsothit.}`

Comment: Always replace the longest first. Arrange the `replace` commands so that the longest strings are examined before the shorter ones. If I have text `cat`, and I replace `c` with `m`, and *then* I replaced `cat` with `dog`, the result is `mat`. But if I do longest first, the result is `dog`. The spaces are from English letters remaining in the output but the font is Bengali, if you are still using the Noto fonts.

Comment: The tokenn list was being repeated: I have fixed MWE code,

Comment: [Cicada](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182648/cicada) I can't fix a problem regarding `া, ি, ী, ু, ূ ` etc. For example, `\bn{amra}` should be `আমরা`, but I get the output `ামরা খাই` or `আমরআ খআই`। How can I set `আ` and `া` with a single charater `a` or `-a` ?

Comment: Make the "from" unique strings. `a` is 1-character string, `-a` is 2-character string. You can do, say, from `a` to  া  , and from `-a` to আ (but `-a` must come *before* `a` in the `replace` sequence because it is longer). You can do any (unique) strings: from `lettera` to আ, and from `vowela` to  া. Always the longest strings must be `replace`d before the shorter ones. Alternatively, if the pattern is regular, example "`a` at  the beginning of a word becomes আ", then a **regex** expression could be used.

Comment: Your **Bangla to Latin** works fine replacing both `আ` and `া` using single letter `a`. But I want the reverse. How can I set **regex** expression for it?

Comment: Do `texdoc interface3`, see part XXVIII, page 226: all about regex command. With both regex and with replace, the testing sequence is important. I'll see if I can do an example regex for you (maybe, don't have much time at the moment). Better: ask a separate question, so more eyes see it.

Comment: I have asked the [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619931/transliteration-of-vowels-and-joint-letters-in-benglai-problem) in details. Can you have a look on it now or later?. I am eagerly waiting for your answer.