# Generating Phonetic Bangla from Engilsh Problem

Tags: transliteration, phonetic

From the answer of this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619715/how-to-generate-phonetic-transliteration-from-english-to-bengali/619742#619742), I have edited the code to minimize like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\translitfont{Kalpurush.ttf}
\newfontface\bengalifont{Kalpurush.ttf}[Script=Bengali,Renderer=HarfBuzz]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_mytrans_tl
% transliteration: Latin-to-Bangla
\NewDocumentCommand{\bn}{ m }
{
\tl_set:Nn \l_mytrans_tl { #1 }
\dobntrans
    { \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl }
    { \bengalifont \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl }
}
\newcommand\dobntrans{
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ng } { ং } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { jh } { ঝ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { NG } { ঞ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Th } { ঠ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Dh } { ঢ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { th } { থ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { dh } { ধ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ph } { ফ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { bh } { ভ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { sh } { শ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Sh } { ষ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Rh } { ঢ় } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { kh } { খ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { gh } { ঘ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Ng } { ঙ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ch } { ছ } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { o= } { অ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { a= } { আ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { i= } { ই } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ii= } { ঈ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { u= } { উ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { uu= } { ঊ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { r= } { ঋ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { e= } { এ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ai= } { ঐ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { oo= } { ও } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { au= } { ঔ } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { a } { া } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { i } { ি } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { I } { ী } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { u } { ু } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { U } { ূ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { -r } { ৃ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { e } { ে } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ai } { ৈ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { O } { ো } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { au } { ৌ } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { k } { ক } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { g } { গ } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { c } { চ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { j } { জ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { J } { জ } 


\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { T } { ট } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { D } { ড } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { N } { ণ } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { t } { ত } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { d } { দ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { n } { ন } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { p } { প } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { f } { ফ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { b } { ব } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { v } { ভ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { m } { ম } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { z } { য } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { r } { র } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { l } { ল } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { S } { শ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { s } { স } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { H } { হ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { R } { ড় } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { y } { য় }
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Y } { য় }
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { t- } { ৎ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { : } { ঃ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ^ } { ঁ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { o } { ্ }

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 0 } { ০ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 1 } { ১ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 2 } { ২ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 3 } { ৩ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 4 } { ৪ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 5 } { ৫ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 6 } { ৬ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 7 } { ৭ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 8 } { ৮ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 9 } { ৯ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { . } { । } 
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\section{\bn{banglay likhi}}
\bn{a=mader desh bangladesh. a=mra banglay ktha bli. bangladesh e=kTi chOToT desh. e=Ti dkoShiN e=Siya mHadeshe o=bsothit.}
\end{document}
```

. But I got output like this which contains a lot of space (red marked):

[image]

My Question is: **How could I remove this spaces using minimal code?**

Comment: That was @[Cicada](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182648/cicada)'s answer.

Comment: Change `\dobntrans  { \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl }` to `\dobntrans`.

Comment: @[Cicada](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182648/cicada) It works magically! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I have updated code in the other answer. Good work on the transliteration side!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\bn` command was incorrectly repeating the token list.

The correct definition is:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\bn}{ m }
{
\tl_set:Nn \l_mytrans_tl { #1 }
\dobntrans
   
    { \bengalifont \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl }
}
```

Comment: [Cicada](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182648/cicada) I can't fix a problem regarding `া, ি, ী, ু, ূ ` etc. For example, `\bn{amra}` should be `আমরা`, but I get the output `ামরা খাই` or `আমরআ খআই`। How can I set `আ` and `া` with a single charater `a` or `-a` ?

Comment: You need to tell TeX what to do: either a regex function ("`a` at the beginning of a word becomes আ otherwise becomes া"), or you need to hard-code the choice (e.g., `aa` is replaced with আ and `a` becomes   া", with `aa` processed before `a`). Another way is regex again: " া at beginning of word becomes আ ").