# Transliteration of vowels and joint letters in Benglai problem

Tags: transliteration, phonetic

**Issue 1: Vowels**

I can't fix a problem regarding with `া, ি, ী, ু, ূ` etc. bangla vowels. For example, if I write `\bn{amra khai}` using following MWE, it should be `আমরা খাই`, but I get the output `ামরা াম খাই` or `আমরআ আম খআই`. How can I set both `আ` and `া` with a single charater `a`?

| Same thing happens for other vowels: |
| --- |
| i for ই/ি |
| i for ঈ/ী |
| i for উ/ু etc. |

**Issue 2: Joint letters**

Normally Bangla language join two or more letters into one. Say, `ক্ত`, `ক্ক`, `ক্ল` etc. When we write phonetically, Bangla letters join each other by default (with hosonto '্‌'). If we want not to join letter we use extra `o` after the letter. For instance, `ভক্ত` should be wirtten as `vokto`. If I write `kolom`, it changes to `কলম`.

| More examples: |
| --- |
| poncom পঞ্চম |
| somman সম্মান |
| sontan সন্তান |
| oTTalika অট্টালিকা |
| cihn চিহ্ন |

How can I solve these issues changing the following MWE or another solutions?

My working MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mapping}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\bengalifont{Kalpurush.ttf}[Script=Bengali,Renderer=HarfBuzz]

\ExplSyntaxOn

% transliteration: Latin-to-Bangla
\NewDocumentCommand{\bn}{ m }
{
\tl_set:Nn \l_mytrans_tl { #1 }
\dobntrans 
    { \bengalifont \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl }
}

\newcommand\dobntrans{
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { kh } { খ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { gh } { ঘ} 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Ng } { ঙ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ch } { ছ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ng } { ং } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { jh } { ঝ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { NG } { ঞ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Th } { ঠ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Dh } { ঢ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { th } { থ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { dh } { ধ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ph } { ফ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { bh } { ভ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { sh } { শ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Sh } { ষ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Rh } { ঢ় } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { rr } { ্র } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { o= } { অ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { A } { আ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { I } { ই } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ii= } { ঈ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { U } { উ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { uu= } { ঊ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { r= } { ঋ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { E } { এ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ai= } { ঐ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { oo= } { ও } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { au= } { ঔ } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { a } { া } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { i } { ি } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { I } { ী } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { u } { ু } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { U } { ূ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { -r } { ৃ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { e } { ে } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ai } { ৈ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { O} { ো } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { au} { ৌ } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { k } { ক } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { g } { গ } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { c } { চ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { j } { জ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { J } {জ } 


\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { T } { ট } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { D } { ড } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { N } { ণ } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { t } { ত } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { d } { দ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { n } { ন } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { p } { প } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { f } { ফ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { b } { ব } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { v } { ভ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { m } { ম } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { z } { য } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { r } { র } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { l } { ল } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { S } { শ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { s } { স } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { H } { হ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { R } { ড় } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { y } { য় }
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Y } { য় }
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { t- } { ৎ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { : } { ঃ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ^ } { ঁ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { o } { ্ }

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { w } { ্ব } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Z } { ্য } 
%\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { rr } { ্র } 


\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 0 } { ০ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 1 } { ১ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 2 } { ২ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 3 } { ৩ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 4 } { ৪ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 5 } { ৫ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 6 } { ৬ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 7 } { ৭ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 8 } { ৮ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 9 } { ৯ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { . } { । } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { : } { : } 
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{\bn{banglay likhi}}
\bn{amader desh bangladesh. amra banglay kotha boli. bangladesh ekTi chOTT desh. eTi dkoShiN ESiyay obsothit.}

\bn{bangladesh ekTi swadhIn desh. 1971 sale ek rokotkShokhI zuddher madhZme ei desh swadhInota lav kore. amader ucit seI swadhInota somunnot rakha.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have `\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { a } { া } ` in your code which replaces `a` with `া`. So obviously `amra` would render `ামরা`. How would the program know when you want `আ` and when `া`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what exactly is the problem in issue no. two? If `klant` is rendered as `ক` + `্` + `ল` + `া` + `ন` + `্` + `ত`; then I assume it is rendering the word correctly. What's the issue?

Comment: Great to see someone is trying to use LaTeX for writing Bengali too. I don't have any clue about Your problem but I am pleased to see this.

Comment: Also IMO `\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { o } { ্ }` is absolutely counterintuitive. In your output `boli` is rendered as `ব্লি` and I am sure this is not what you intended. I think what you indeed need is having হসন্ত (hosonto) automatically every time and **not having it** when the `o` comes. So that way `o=bosthito` would be rendered as `অবস্থিত`.

Comment: [Niranjan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/174620/niranjan) I have edited the question. The problem is with rokto/vokto etc.

Comment: [Niranjan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/174620/niranjan) Yes, you are right. I am not sure how to set regex expression or else for it? I don't want to do _hard code_ for it.

Comment: It's quite tough. I have been thinking about doing something similar for Devanagari, but turns out that there are a lot of complexities :(

Comment: but at least for Devanagari we have Velthuis and many fonts support internal conversion from Velthuis input to Unicode output. Hence if I set `\setmainfont[Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit,Script=Devanagari,Language=Default]{Sanskrit2003}` in my preamble and write `ga.naadhii"sa`; then it's rendered correctly as `गणाधीश`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130790/discussion-between-niranjan-and-masudur).