# Transliteration of vowels in Benglai problem

Tags: expl3, transliteration, phonetic

**Vowels Problem**

I can't fix a problem regarding with `া, ি, ী, ু, ূ` etc. bangla vowels. For example, if I write `\bn{amra khai}` using following MWE, it should be `আমরা খাই`, but I get the output `ামরা াম খাই` or `আমরআ আম খআই`. How can I set both `আ` and `া` with a single charater `a`?

| Same thing happens for other vowels: |
| --- |
| i for ই/ি |
| i for ঈ/ী |
| i for উ/ু etc. |

How can I solve this issues changing the following MWE or another solutions?

My working MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mapping}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\bengalifont{Kalpurush.ttf}[Script=Bengali,Renderer=HarfBuzz]

\ExplSyntaxOn

% transliteration: Latin-to-Bangla
\NewDocumentCommand{\bn}{ m }
{
\tl_set:Nn \l_mytrans_tl { #1 }
\dobntrans 
    { \bengalifont \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl }
}

\newcommand\dobntrans{
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { kh } { খ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { gh } { ঘ} 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Ng } { ঙ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ch } { ছ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ng } { ং } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { jh } { ঝ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { NG } { ঞ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Th } { ঠ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Dh } { ঢ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { th } { থ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { dh } { ধ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ph } { ফ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { bh } { ভ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { sh } { শ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Sh } { ষ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Rh } { ঢ় } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { rr } { ্র } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { o= } { অ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { A } { আ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { I } { ই } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ii= } { ঈ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { U } { উ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { uu= } { ঊ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { r= } { ঋ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { E } { এ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ai= } { ঐ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { oo= } { ও } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { au= } { ঔ } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { a } { া } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { i } { ি } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { I } { ী } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { u } { ু } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { U } { ূ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { -r } { ৃ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { e } { ে } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ai } { ৈ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { O} { ো } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { au} { ৌ } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { k } { ক } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { g } { গ } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { c } { চ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { j } { জ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { J } {জ } 


\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { T } { ট } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { D } { ড } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { N } { ণ } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { t } { ত } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { d } { দ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { n } { ন } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { p } { প } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { f } { ফ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { b } { ব } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { v } { ভ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { m } { ম } 

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { z } { য } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { r } { র } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { l } { ল } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { S } { শ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { s } { স } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { H } { হ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { R } { ড় } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { y } { য় }
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Y } { য় }
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { t- } { ৎ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { : } { ঃ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { ^ } { ঁ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { o } { ্ }

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { w } { ্ব } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { Z } { ্য } 
%\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { rr } { ্র } 


\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 0 } { ০ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 1 } { ১ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 2 } { ২ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 3 } { ৩ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 4 } { ৪ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 5 } { ৫ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 6 } { ৬ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 7 } { ৭ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 8 } { ৮ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { 9 } { ৯ } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { . } { । } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { : } { : } 
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{\bn{banglay likhi}}
\bn{amader desh bangladesh. amra banglay kotha boli. bangladesh ekTi chOTT desh. eTi dkoShiN ESiyay obsothit.}

\bn{bangladesh ekTi swadhIn desh. 1971 sale ek rokotkShokhI zuddher madhZme ei desh swadhInota lav kore. amader ucit seI swadhInota somunnot rakha.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you would get more answers if you would give more details how you want this to behave. Is the transliteration schema you want to apply documented somewhere? What are the rules under which `আ` or `া` should be shown?

Comment: [Didn't you ask a very similar question yesterday?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619931/transliteration-of-vowels-and-joint-letters-in-benglai-problem)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger it's ISO 15919 and an algirithm is written out in David Jones paper https://github.com/davidmjones/brahmic-maps/blob/master/brahmic.pdf  I guess you could do a similar mapping in the Lua font handler. see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15919

Comment: I think (from trying) it might be a font issue. Can you try with NotoSansBengali? Also cut your test to only two words so it is easy to test.

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597535/how-to-generate-transliteration-of-bengali-word for a reverse mapping question

Comment: @Masudur Use `@...` to ping a user; otherwise they will not know unless they come back and look.

Comment: `@Marcel Krüger`, you are right in both of you queries. But I could not get the answer.

Comment: `@David Carlisle` Can you help me out to making reverse of your answer in that question?

Comment: `@Cicada` is that OK?

Answer (score 1):

with xetex you can use a teckit mapping, but I can't read this to say how well it behaves

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\bengalifont{Kalpurush}[Script=Bengali,Mapping=beng]

\newcommand\bn[1]{{\bengalifont#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{\bn{banglay likhi}}
\bn{amader desh bangladesh. amra banglay kotha boli. bangladesh ekTi chOTT desh. eTi dkoShiN ESiyay obsothit.}

\bn{bangladesh ekTi swadhIn desh. 1971 sale ek rokotkShokhI zuddher madhZme ei desh swadhInota lav kore. amader ucit seI swadhInota somunnot rakha.}

\end{document}
```

I used the `beng.map` and `beng.tex` from

https://github.com/davidmjones/brahmic-maps

If the mapping needs adjusting you can modify your copy of `beng.map` and recompile with `teckit_compile`

Comment: Thanks David. Could you help me with one of your previous answer. Link is given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597545/243840). I  can't modify your answer which is reverse of my ones. Could you use this to make it reverse?

Comment: It's not in the right way that you answered above.

Comment: @Masudur I am very confused, one of your earlier questions asked about the reverse mapping but the example you post in this question is just about `bn{banglay likhi}` so ascii input and Bengali typesetting. If that is not what you want I think you need to completely rewrite the question???

Comment: @Masudur does this answer post actually answer the question in the title about vowels? (I honestly can not tell which are vowel forms in the output so I have no idea if the typeset text I show here  is even readable)

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough information as to what you trying to achieve, but most importantly give some guidelines as to what transcription standard you want to follow and why?

1. Choose a scheme from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanisation_of_Bengali and let us know.
2. Romanization or transliteration is normally used as an input tool. Currently there are much better tools available. (try google input tools).
3. The only advantage doing it through LaTeX is for short sentences say for a tutorial?

Now some guidelines as to the parsing:

1. Always split the input into words. Parsing through words will be faster, and also if characters change if they are at a particular position in the word, you can cater for this. Many writing systems  combine letters when they are in the middle of a word in a different way if they are at the end or beginning.
2. Accents, are always problematic, so you need tests using short words first.

[image]

3. You can see here for example the problem with `t-` at number 10. I think from a cursory look you got the same issue with the `r's`. **order of parsing is important.**
4. Simple replacements might not be the right answer. A better way will be with regular expressions, and the best with Lua Lpeg.
5. Personally, as I hate committees, situated in some Bureaucracy in Brussels and using outdated thinking, I would change the concept and provide a word dictionary with a an algorithm based on `trie` structure. They can be very fast. With a dictionary of about 5000 words you will probably not even notice the compiler time. if the language has verb endings that change, it might be a bit more involved.
6. Where I think transcription is valuable is on extinct scripts, such as say the Anatolian script, or the Indus script, where researchers are used to using symbolic names and or numbers, say in Cretan Linear B, one might write JAR to get  and AMPH to get .

The code for the image is:

```
\bengalifont\Huge
 1  \bn{ti}    = ti \\
 2  \bn{ta}    = ta\\
 3  \bn{te}    = te \\
 4  \bn{to}    = to\\
 5  \bn{to=}   = to=?\\
 6  \bn{tu}    = tu\\
 7  \bn{tuu=}   = tou?\\
 8  \bn{uu=t}  = ?\\
 9  \bn{tuu=}  = ?\\
 10 \bn{t-u}   = ?\\    % PROBLEM 
 11 \bn{bangladesh}\\
 12 \bn{amra khai} =    = আমরা খাই\\
 13 \bn{kai}
```